# Error in file (with, "r") from running querxc package warbleR

Tags: r, warbler

I have an error about Error in file (with, "r") – (below Error) from running querxc (). I have done several Google searches and found very little. Did you see this error in packege WarbleR? Can anybody help me ?

> cabanisi  <- querxc(qword = "Synallaxis cabanisi ", download = FALSE)
>   Obtaining recording list...
>   Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(con, "r") :
>     InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Uma solicitação de redirecionamento transformará uma conexão não segura em segura'

Comment: just venturing a guess, you are prob behind some firewall and need to set the proxy using `Sys.setenv(http_proxy="mycompanyproxyserver:8080");Sys.setenv(https_proxy="mycompanyproxyserver:8080")`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran it and it worked fine:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPoNs.png)

warbleR version 1.1.9